# How to fill shelf with objects?

Tags: particles

I created a shelf for medicine and want to fill it with boxes.[image] I think I can use particle system for that purpose, but I can't use animation cause in that case the boxes with medicine will be too random. I created vertex group from selected faces and use hair system to spawn boxes, but there are problems: 1) boxes are overlapping themselves; 2) I can't randomize boxes size in different coordinates; 3) I can't place boxes over themselves.
For now I getting this:[image]
Result I trying to get:[image]
Is it possible or I should do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?
[image]

I got there with just one cube.

Add it to the shelf by using snapping (to face)
[image]

Then add an array modifier to the cube. Select how many boxes you want on the x axis. I set mine to 1.320 to put spaces between them.

Then add a second array modifier, this time selecting the z axis. This will stack the boxes on top. Set z to 1 so there are no gaps.

I added a slight value to y so the boxes sit back slightly and you can see them clearly.

[image]

Apply the modifiers.
Go into EDIT mode. Select all by tapping A. Then hit 'P' to separate by parts.

Go back to OBJECT mode. You can now change the position and sizes of all the boxes together.

Select all of the boxes you want to adjust.

Go to the OBJECT menu - Transform - Randomize transform.

[image]

From here you can change the size of the boxes and where they sit on one another. Play around with the settings. Don't change location Z or the objects will float above or collide with each other.

You can also adjust the rotation on the Z axis slightly. It all depends how neatly you want the boxes stacked.

Comment: It works but seems like snapping option doesn't work for me. What are you using in "Snap to..." option? I'm using face project and "snap with" -> "Median".

Comment: There should be a little magnet icon next to the proportional edit icon on the top-middle of the screen. That icon is the "snap to" icon.